# Dangers of lengthening IIS app pool recycle interval

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, application-pool

I have a .NET application running in IIS7 that has a very large connected service attached to it. Because it is so large, the site takes a very long time (10-15 minutes) to "spool up" again after the app pool is recycled (it's currently set to the default recycle interval of every 29 hours or something). My problem is that in the environment I'm working in, having an application that takes that long to start every morning isn't acceptable. So my question is, what are the dangers of setting the app pool to recycle less frequently? Say once a week or even once a month? The application will be running on its own pool, so other applications don't need to be taken into account. Thanks!

Comment: One of the goals of application pool recycle is to address memory related issues of flawed web apps, so literally speaking if your app has no memory issue (who knows) you can totally disable it. As it really depends on your web app itself, I suggest you do some memory profiling with the developers and then try to change the setting to a large value with proactive monitoring.

Comment: Solid explanation, thanks!